# Select the data which starts from this alphabets?

Tags: mysql

```
select * from airports 
where field_name
like %A% and field_name like %B% and field_name like %C% and field_name like %D%
and field_name like %E% and field_name like %F% and field_name like %G% 
and field_name like %H% and field_name like %I% and field_name like %J%
and field_name like %K% and field_name like %L% and field_name like %M%
and field_name like %N% and field_name like %O% and field_name like %P% 
and field_name like %Q% and field_name like %R% and field_name like %S%
and field_name like %T% and field_name like %V% and field_name like %U%
and field_name like %W% and field_name like %Y% and field_name like %Z%
```

Comment: '%A%' would be used to check if the field contains an `A` rather than just starts with `A`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `where` keyword for your column and instead of `and` use `or` condition.

Something like this:

```
select * from airports where 
column_name like 'A%' or column_name like 'B%' ......
```

Also if you want to check that the column name starts with a particular alphabet then the wildcard character should be last only like

```
column_name like 'A%'
```

or better use REGEX:

```
WHERE column_name REGEXP '^[A-Z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `LOCATE()` to query the first letter against a string comprising the letters you're interested in:

```
WHERE LOCATE(LEFT(field_name, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ')
```

That will return results where `name` starts with any of those alphabets (which is practically all possible letters safe for X).

Or, using a regular expression:

```
WHERE field_name REGEXP '^[A-Z]'
```

Change the character set where needed.